# How to sum values of multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM 
    sys.all.column 
WHERE object_id = (SELECT object_id 
                   FROM sys.all_objects 
                   WHERE name ='name of my table' and type = 'TT') 
  AND name NOT IN (list of columns that I don't need)
```

How do I sum all the values of the returned columns from the preceding SQL query?

Comment: what do you mean by `sum all the values of the returned columns`? By the looks of it, name is probably a text column. Sum of what?

Comment: The code will return all the columns in tye specified table. I want to sum the value of each column of a particular row

Comment: so you want to sum column the values of a single row?  Why can't you just write the column names -- how many columns do you have?

Comment: oh you want sum of all the columns of a particular row?

Comment: Are you looking to create a dynamic query to sum columns from the table on the fly?

Comment: is this sql server?  do you mean sys.all_objects?

Comment: the columns are not known. it changes

Comment: it is sqlserver Hogan

Comment: in what crazy model do you columns change?

Comment: sorry it is sys.all_object

Comment: Don't think that's possible. `sys.all_columns` has meta data (such as the name of the columns and the corresponding tables). You need a select query.

Comment: The columns are added at runtime

Comment: yes this is my point.  This is not a nosql system, this is a relational system your columns should not be added at run time.  This is an indication of a bad design or a poor tool choice.

Comment: Hogan... the code is for windows application for an organization. It creates a column every end of the month to update deduction from the members for that particular month

Comment: HOWEVER, if you used the XML extensions and stored XML data with variable "columns" that could be a good way to get around the limitation of  relational systems and be dynamic -- failing that you have to use dynamic SQL which can be bad.

Comment: The correct way to solve that "problem" in a relational database is to have a column called "month" and at the end of every month add ROWS and in those rows put the month and year in the month column.

Comment: @JustinOfodile Are columns added every month ? So for example at the end of this year there will be 12 additional columns? If not as Hogan says, it can simply be retained or updated. You can then use a static query (assuming you have a say in the schema design).

Comment: @RavindraHV -- yes that is what he just said.  It is 100% bad design and he should change it right away.

Comment: Thanks so much Hogan. I appreciate but how would you solve such a problem where you need to record the savings of about 300 members of an organization every month? Thank you

Comment: @JustinOfodile - From my end, can think of two options - 1) Have a separate table (the join would cost you but if only 300 records then join would not be a problem) - `MemberId,Year,Month,Savings`. Then you could add up the rows. 2) If there are millions of records and for performance reasons you have to add new columns, then go ahead and use Gurwinder Singh's or John Cappelletti's approach. But that said, adding columns to a live database with millions of records at runtime (dynamically) is neither simple nor quick (performance-wise).

Comment: Justing -- exactly as I said -- if you had a month column I would add 300 rows each month -- this is MUCH better than adding a column every month.  You could look into some data modeling reference books to see this is a standard leading practice.

Comment: @RavindraHV -- there is no performance case I can think of where 2 is better than 1 with an index.

Comment: Hogan please can you help me on this project..... can I get your contact?

Answer (score 2):

Another option which does not require dynamic SQL, but only a CROSS APPLY or two

Just for fun, I add Min, Max, and Avg just to illustrate... Also added a PctOfTotal or Common-Size

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,CustName varchar(50),Sales_Jan int,Sales_Feb int,Sales_Mar int)
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'John Smith',25,25,50),
(2,'Jane Doe'  ,35,20,null)

Select A.*
      ,C.*
      ,PctOfTotal = Format(C.Total*1.0/Sum(C.Total) over (),'0.00%')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData=cast((Select A.* For XML RAW) as xml)) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Total = Sum(Value)
                      ,Min   = Min(Value)
                      ,Max   = Max(Value)
                      ,Avg   = Avg(Value)
                 From  (
                        Select Value  = attr.value('.','int') 
                         From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                         Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Like 'Sales_%'
                         --Or you can Exclude Specific Columns
                         --Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','CustName')
                       ) S
             ) C
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: exactly as I was saying -- use xml.  very cute answer. Does it get slow where there are a lot of columns.... this guy is adding 12 a year.

Comment: @Hogan I'm assuming "cute answer" is a compliment and not just mocking me :)   Performance is respectable.  Just ran a test on 6,681 records with 24 columns to add (yield curve rates).   Results returned in 0.634 seconds (while streaming NetFlix)

Comment: yes cute answer was a compliment -- this technique is def. going in my bag of tricks.  (transport speed has little effect on performance would be my guess -- so who cares about NetFlix?)  I'll try it on a couple million rows when I get in on Tuesday and let you know.

Comment: @Hogan Please do, but I can't this would be my approach on a millions of rows.. odds are I would re-think the structure.  The 6,681 records was the only table I had that fit his model.  Hopefully, this will buy him a little time to change his structure,

Comment: @Hogan In all honesty, the word cute made me smile.  It was unexpected from someone of your ranking/reputation... Yeah, we watch and follow..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to find out some columns from meta tables that you want to sum, and then sum those columns on the given table. You can use dynamic SQL to achieve this:

```
create table t(a integer, b integer, c integer);

insert into t values(1,2,3);

declare @tab varchar(100);
declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql = '';
set @tab = 't';

select @sql = @sql + '+' + a.name from sys.all_columns a
inner join 
sys.all_objects b
on a.object_id = b.object_id
where b.name = @tab
and a.name not in ('c');

set @sql = 'select ' + stuff(@sql, 1, 1, '') + ' from ' + @tab;

exec(@sql);
```

Produces:

```
3
```

Comment: @Hogan `and a.name not in ('c');` to give example of how to ignore a column

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Just remember this answer the next time you mock my dynamic pivots.  :) --- Happy New Year!

Comment: @JohnCappelleti Hey.. Happy new year. I tried a bit and it worked but obviously no match for yours. :)

Comment: @John I admire your queries. I am sorry if you felt that I was mocking them.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh  Honestly, never thought that for a second. 1) I'm pretty thick skinned.  2) I have a GREAT sense of humor  and 3) If you want to mock me, you'd better up your game... my wife was going to turn pro.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,NVL(col1,0)+NVL(col2,0)+NVL(col3,0)+NVL(col4,0)
from
(select *
from sys.all.column
where object_id =(select object_id from sys.all.object where name ='name of my table') 
  and name not in (list of columns that I dont need).)


   A  |  B   |  Total(col1+col2)
------+------+-------
   1  |  2   |   3
---------------------
   1  |      |   1
```

Whatever columns you get, sum it and put them as  seperate column in the result table.

Comment: This answer is very wrong.  Please test and see why.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing here.

Comment: @Hogan.: what ver be the result then  just get the summed value from the columns.

Comment: why do you think sys.all.column (which does not exist btw) would have a column named "col1"? (or "col2" etc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131984/discussion-between-coderredoc-and-hogan).